# Tools for learning Assembly in "The Art of Intel X86 Assembly"

Tags: assembly

Although I studied a Computer Organization course in my college, I want to study Assembly (and related concepts) rigorously using this old book: [The Art of Intel X86 Assembly](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~pannain/mc404/aulas/pdfs/Art%20Of%20Intel%20x86%20Assembly.pdf). Do you know how to get start on Linux? Is NASM a good choice for this? If I want to incorporate [UCR Standard Library](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/DOS/Software.html) in my code, do I have to compile the library first?

I want my code to run on a Linux VM (Virtual Box). Is this possible or it must be the native code of my machine?

Comment: I got basic understanding of computer organization and assembly in my uni time, but not as rigorous as in the book. Now I just want to have a quick start over required environment, so I can focus on studying, if anyone has similar experience in studying with the book.

Comment: x86 is a horrible first assembly language, I hope this is not your first...msp430, pdp11, arm are all much better first instruction sets...definitely use a simulator (having the hardware is a bad excuse for learning that one first)...If you have to do x86 then use something like pcemu or bochs or something like that.  Or make your own if you REALLY want to learn this stuff, it is actually pretty easy to make your own instruction set simulator.

Comment: I programmed in Motorola 68k before. Now I want to learn x86. The problem with the textbook is that the applications are old (some can only run in DOS/Windows 3.1). I'm finding a solution to create similar environment in Linux. I've just tried dosbox, but it seems not to work. The book is really nice. It even shows how to use BIOS calls and interrupts and implement state machines in ASM and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to overcome this issue.

I was trying various solutions, including download ReactOS to run such legacy programs. Suddenly I remembered good old Wine, and found out that Wine was originally made for 16-bit applications running under DOS and Windows 3.1. As a result, I can use all of the applications now. If a program can only be used with DOS, dosbox comes into play.

To run a Windows program, I use `wine <Windows_program>`; to run a DOS program: `dosbox <dos_program>`. Work great.

With JWAsm, I can use it to substitute MASM32. At this stage, I am still not sure how to link and use UCR Standard Library, but I hope that I will have a solution when encounter this issue.